# Invert legend values for raster in QGIS 3.4.6

Tags: raster, symbology, qgis-3

The legend in the TOC for a raster layer ( > 1 million cells with continuous data) in my view might look like this:
[image: raster legend]

The values go from low (above) to high (down). Is there a way to show the values in reversed order: high values on top and low values below?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the render type **Paletted/Unique values** which allows you to set manually the values:

[image: raster reversed legend order]

Comment: Thanks, but I forgot to mention that I'm dealing with continuous raster datasets (too many individual values to be able to set the legend manually. I'll edit my original question.

Comment: @Jan - You could save the style file as a .qml file then load this into an advanced text editor (e.g. [Sublime](https://www.sublimetext.com/)). Inside the tag `<paletteEntry>` will contain your values and colours etc. If you highlight all of these, you could reverse them (in Sublime it would be from the menubar `Edit > Permute Lines > Reverse`). Save the style file then reapply it to the raster.